# property read from SpringBootTest annotation is null rather than configured value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a simple test code to read property from annotation, but maven test execution gives out "org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected:  but was: "
Can someone please help? I am a starter of Java and Spring.

Here is my code:

```
package org.xyz.mytest;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@SpringBootTest(properties = "foo=bar")
public class ConcreteTest {

    @Value("${foo}")
    String foo;

    @Test
    public void testT4() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(foo, "bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Value` is not compatible with having a SpringBootTest this way.
Use the TestPropertySource annotation to make`@Valid` work

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "foo=bar"   // separated by comma in case there are more properties.
})
```